# Excelljs - how to create a sheet from stream

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I am using [ExcellJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#reading-xlsx) library for manipulating Excell on Node.js(Hapi.js).

I got it to create worksheet based on the file that is uploaded. I did something like this:

```
uploadItems: function (request, reply) {
    var data = request.payload;
    if (data.file) {
        var name = data.file.hapi.filename;
        //var path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
        var path = process.cwd() + "/uploads/" + name;
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

         data.file.on('end', function (err) {
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        var bulkParts = [];
        workbook.xlsx.readFile(path)
            .then(function (workbook) {
                workbook.eachSheet(function (worksheet, sheetId) {
                    worksheet.eachRow({includeEmpty: true}, function (row, rowNumber) {
                        var singleItem = new _Items(data.ProductId, row.values[1], row.values[2]);
                        bulkParts.push(singleItem);
                        console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + JSON.stringify(row.values));
                    });
                });
        file.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err)
        });
        data.file.pipe(file);
    }
         ...
```

This works. This method creates a file from stream, and then I read this file and create my object. I would rather create a file directly from the stream, thus avoiding creation on the disk.

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#reading-xlsx) of the Excell Plugin mentions this:

```
// pipe from stream 
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());
```

But honestly I tried many ways, and just cant get it to creat object from stream.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream()).pipe(file)?

Comment: I will try, How do I access my workbook then? 'Then' is not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your [upload route is configured properly](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options) to accept file streams.
In the example below, `request.payload.file` is your stream that you pass into `workbook.xlsx.read`. Then you can handle the promise.

```
var uploadRoute = {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/upload',
    config: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                file: joi.any()
            }
        },
        payload: {
            maxBytes: 30009715200,
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        description: 'upload an excel file'
    },
    handler: uploadRouteHandler
};

function uploadRouteHandler(request, reply) {

    if (request.payload.file) { // request.payload.file is your stream
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

        workbook.xlsx.read(request.payload.file)
                .then(function(excelworkbook) {
                     /** do stuff with your new workbook here **/
                });
    }
}
```

> 'stream' - the incoming payload is made available via a Stream.Readable interface. If the payload is 'multipart/form-data' and parse is true, fields values are presented as text while files are provided as streams. File streams from a 'multipart/form-data' upload will also have a property hapi containing filename and headers properties.